# How export registered servers settings in Aqua Data Studio?

Tags: aquafold

Does anyone know how to export registered servers in Aqua Data Studio? Maybe there's some tricky method to do it by copying some .ini file or registry keys?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AD Studio server registrations are in [USER_HOME]/.datastudio/connections directory. You can copy your existing connections from one machine to another.
AquaFold's documentation about copying registrations from one computer to another is here:
https://www.aquaclusters.com/app/home/project/public/aquadatastudio/wikibook/Documentation16/page/128/Configuration-Connection-files#copy

Answer (score 1):

*** Note: make sure you take a backup of the  .datastudio before replacing files.

To Export the connections please make sure you have a fresh installation of aqua data studio on the other system and you haven't set up any new connections.

1) Simply go to C:\Users[userName]\.datastudio

copy folders, files below and place in the same location of the new system:

C:\Users[userName]\.datastudio\connections

C:\Users[userName]\.datastudio\bigquery

C:\Users[userName]\.datastudio\pfile.properties

pfile.properties has the cipher key to decrypt passwords on the system.

Answer (score 0):

I initially only copied the connections folder and found none of my passwords worked anymore.  Then I added the pfiles.properties file.  That fixed the password problem, but when I tried to open a Query Analyzer window on any of my many MS SQL Server registered servers, I got an error:  `Id 18456, Level 14, State 1, Line 1 Login failed for user '<username>'.`

By copying the rest of the files and subfolders in the .datastudio folder (except for the history which I didn't need and the license files as I had to renew my license anyway), the error was cleared.  Bottom line, copy the entire .datastudio folder to transfer your configuration to the new machine, as is documented in the aquaclusters Wiki link: "Copying this directory to a new computer copies *all* of your current ADS customizations and server registrations."