# How to export registered servers passwords in Aqua Data Studio?

Tags: aquafold

Does anyone know how to export stored passwords for registered servers in Aqua Data Studio?

To be clear, I want the plain text password for each saved connection.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How export registered servers settings in Aqua Data Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29817430/how-export-registered-servers-settings-in-aqua-data-studio)

Comment: This says where the field are and "pfile.properties has the cipher key to decrypt passwords" but not how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If the intent is to transfer your registered servers to a new laptop, the pfile.properties file needs to be copied to the new device along with the connections subfolder (actually, the entire .datastudio directory).  You don't need them in plaintext to do that.

If you are looking to get the plaintext passwords for another reason, say to switch to a different SQL studio app, I haven't seen any way to do that.